# Predicate Calculus Practice

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I've been doing some practice questions in the textbook for an upcoming predicate calculus lecture and I think I've managed to get A and B (possibly C) correct but I am clueless on how I can manage D and E.

For A I got: ∃x(R(x)∧¬B)

For B I got: ∀x(¬R(x)∧B)

For C I got: ∃x(R(x)∧(x=y))   - Not sure if this is even remotely correct

---

R(X) : ”X is rich”

X = Y : ”X equals Y”

B : ”Bill Gates”

a) Someone besides Bill Gates is rich.

b) Bill Gates alone is rich.

c) At least two people are rich.

d) Exactly one person is rich.

e) Exactly two persons are rich.

The universe of discourse is the set of all people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) $\exists x(R(x) \wedge \neg(x = B))$

b) $\forall x(R(B) \wedge (\neg(x = B) \implies \neg R(x)))$

c) $\exists x (\exists y(R(x) \wedge R(y)))$

d) This one is more or less like b) $\exists x(\forall y(R(x) \wedge (\neg(x = y) \implies \neg R(y))))$

I think I will leave e) to you, since it follows the same idea as b) and d), try it!

Comment: There are also these optional challenge questions that aren't part of the current curriculum but I'm curious to find out what the method of solving these are. I'm unclear how to implement the A(x,y) AND the P(x,y) in the same statements in either D or E. 

(d) Each student who attended the meeting was accompanied by at least
one of his/her parents. (S(x), M(x), A(x, y), P(x, y))
(e) Students are the only people who attended the meeting accompanied by
one of their parents. (S(x), M(x), A(x, y), P(x, y))